# Where does Spring Web Flow/JSP handle form posts when action isn't specified?

Tags: java, jsp, post, spring-webflow, forms

I just ran into the following code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<form:form method="post" commandName="credentials" htmlEscape="true">
    <label for="username"><spring:message code="screen.welcome.label.netid"/></label>
    <spring:message code="screen.welcome.label.netid.accesskey" var="userNameAccessKey"/>
    <form:input cssClass="required" cssErrorClass="error" id="username" tabindex="1" accesskey="${userNameAccessKey}" path="username" autocomplete="false" htmlEscape="true"/>
    <label for="password" class="fl-label"><spring:message code="screen.welcome.label.password"/></label>
    <spring:message code="screen.welcome.label.password.accesskey" var="passwordAccessKey"/>
    <form:password cssClass="required" cssErrorClass="error" id="password" tabindex="2" path="password" accesskey="${passwordAccessKey}" htmlEscape="true" autocomplete="off"/>
</form:form>
```

And noticed that no `action` attribute was provided. This is a JSP app that uses Spring Web Flow. What does JSP do with form posts under this scenario? How could I find the section of code that actually handles the HTTP POST (form submission)?

Comment: In HTML no action means it submits back to the same page, which here would be the controller for this JSP.

Answer (score 0):

Spring's `<form:form>` tag posts back to the flow path if it is not explicitly specified. Here's an example of generated HTML source from one of my flows:

```
<form id="model-bean" action="/context-root/flow-id?execution=eXsY" method="post">
```